# C# List<> - Insert into database

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have this app where i get data from a `TextBox`, insert it into a `List<>` and then display a new line in the `CheckBoxList`.
Example:

```
List<string> quantidade = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < CheckBoxListLinhas.Items.Count; i++)
{
   quantidade.Add(TextBoxQuantidade.Text.ToString());
}
List<string> artigo = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < CheckBoxListLinhas.Items.Count; i++)
{
   artigo.Add(TextBoxArtigo.Text.ToString());
}
List<string> valor = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < CheckBoxListLinhas.Items.Count; i++)
{
   valor.Add(TextBoxValor.Text.ToString());
}
/*List<string> artigo = new List<string>();
  for (int i = 0; i < CheckBoxListLinhas.Items.Count; i++)
  {
    artigo.Add(TextBoxArtigo.Text.ToString());
  }*/

CheckBoxListLinhas.Items.Add(new ListItem("Quantidade: " + TextBoxQuantidade.Text + " Artigo: " + TextBoxArtigo.Text + " Valor: " + TextBoxValor.Text) + " Anexo: " + FileUpload1.FileName.ToString());
```

And then I want to insert every row from that `List<>` to the database and I already have this example:

```
SqlCommand sqlInsertList = new SqlCommand("Insert into linhas (quantidade,descricao,valor) VALUES(@quantidade,@descricao,@valor)", sqlConn);
sqlInsertList.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantidade", );
sqlInsertList.Parameters.AddWithValue("@descricao", TextBoxArtigo.Text);
sqlInsertList.Parameters.AddWithValue("@valor", float.Parse(TextBoxValor.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat));

sqlConn.Open();                         
sqlTran = sqlConn.BeginTransaction();
sqlInsert.Transaction = sqlTran;        
sqlInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();             
sqlTran.Commit();
```

What is the easiest way I can do that and adapt my `SQLInsert`?

Comment: this is the easiest...

Comment: @Aristos Maybe i wasn't clear enough, i wan't to do it with a `for` cycle, so I can add every row from the `List<>`

Comment: Perhaps you should start to use a `List<Article>`  and not three different lists

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: ASP.NET has nothing to do with databases. What you posted are ADO.NET classes

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you for the correction, I still consider myself a newbie in this technology

Comment: Searching for the wrong technology can lead to frustration. There are a lot of tutorials for ADO.NET, including free courses in Microsoft's Virtual Academy

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you for the advice, I will keep an eye on that in the future

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlCommand sqlInsertList = new SqlCommand("Insert into linhas (quantidade,descricao,valor) VALUES(@quantidade,@descricao,@valor)", sqlConn);   

sqlConn.Open();                         
sqlTran = sqlConn.BeginTransaction();

for (int i = 0; i < quantidade.Count; i++)
{
    sqlInsertList.Transaction = sqlTran;

    sqlInsertList.Parameters.Clear();
    sqlInsertList.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantidade", quantidade[i]);
    sqlInsertList.Parameters.AddWithValue("@descricao", artigo[i]);
    sqlInsertList.Parameters.AddWithValue("@valor", loat.Parse(valor[i], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat));        
    sqlInsertList.ExecuteNonQuery();    
}         
sqlTran.Commit();
```

Comment: @Kawaii I haven't tested it, but that should be it. May I also suggest that you use `List<YourClass>` instead of three string lists (where `YourClass` would contain props `Quandido`, `Artigo` and `Valor`)

Comment: I have an error in `nd("Insert into linhas (quantidade,descricao,valor) VALUES(@quantidade,@descricao,@valor)", sqlConn);`, it says that nd method does not exist. And it also says that method `quantidade`, `artigo` and `valor` don't exist in `sqlInsertLines`.

Comment: that was copy/paste error, I've fixed it. Don't just copy paste it, try to understand the suggested answer. :)

Comment: What is `sqlInsert`?  Is that just a typo of `sqlInsertList`?

Comment: @Nino I can't acess my Lists, is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: @juharr I think it is

Comment: @Kawaii are those lists in scope? Are they in same method as `sqlInsertList`

Comment: @Nino I solved the acess, they were in a different places, but the data is not registred into the database